# ODIN crash flashing tar file in AP

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, flush

Inside OS X Virtual Box with Windows 10 I try to flash my bootloader (TWRP) into a Samsung Galaxy Note 3. In all Odin versions I tried - up to the current latest (v3.12.7) Odin allows to locate the tar file, tells its size. On Start it stops crashing calling a debugger (which I do not have on that windows installation), so I have no idea why it crashes.

The phone is a "reconditioned" phone (chinese with chinese ROM) which I would like to flush. Odin recognizes the USB3 phone port.

When put in download mode, the phone says the following:

```
ODIN MODE
PRODUCT NAME: SM-N9005
CURRENT BINARY: Custom
SYSTEM STATUS: Custom
REACTIVATION LOCK(KK): OFF
KNOX KERNEL LOCK: 0x0
KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 0x1
QUALCOMM SECUREBOOT: ENABLE (CSB)
AP SWREV: S2, T2, A2, A3, P3
WRITE PROTECTION: Enable
UDC START
```

And downstairs the phone "says": Downloading - do not turn off target!!

I have uninstalled and reinstalled https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336 on the windows VM (and rebooted it).

How can I solve this please? I already read tons of blogs and have still no visibility (up to buying a too expensive windows debugger)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you do not need to use virtual box to flash your phone you can do it by using OSX

Step 1: You need to install Java on your MAC OSX [https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml](https://bitbucket.org/benjamin_dobell/heimdall/downloads/heimdall-suite-1.4.0-mac.dmg)

Step 2: Next, you need to install Hemidall https://bitbucket.org/benjamin_dobell/heimdall/downloads/heimdall-suite-1.4.0-mac.dmg

Now, you need to get rid of Samsung Kies installed on your MacBook

Step 3: Now Download Odin3 for Mac OSX https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ZC2H74coZrREE2NzU2NVZPSEE/view